# Genius USB Keyboard KB-M220 doesn't work

Tags: windows-7, keyboard

I have a Genius USB Keyboard, model KB-M220.

The guide says that it works in Windows 7.

I have Windows 7 Professional 64 bits and the keyboard doesn't work here.

This is how it appears in device manager:

[image]

If anyone can help, I would be grateful

Regards.

Comment: Did you install the driver?

Comment: Thanks for your response.

I don't find any driver avaiable in the net for W7 64 bits.

I've searched a lot of time.... but nothing :(

Apparently, this keyboard doesn't need any driver :S

Comment: It's a common port of my laptop (compaq presario cq60).

It isn't USB 3.0

Comment: Device Manager detect it,as "USB Keyboard", but it can't find a driver, neither at Internet neithar in my computer.

Comment: Under Keyboards appear: "Standard PS/2 Keyboard". And Under Other devices appear "USB Keyboard" like a device without driver.

I show you in this screenshot: [link](http://img202.imageshack.us/img202/4707/sinttulozpa.png)

Comment: I don't know.

I go to try the keyboard in the BIOS.

Comment: I tried in the BIOS, and the keyboard works perfectly!! :S

Comment: I did what you said me. I uninstalled all "Universal Host Controller" in "Universal Serial Bus Controllers".

The laptop restarted, and began to install the "Universal Host Controller". During this time, the keyboard worked perfectly, but when the installation ended, the keyboard doesn't work again... :S

Answer (score 0):

As per our comments, try the keyboard in the BIOS to prove if it is a driver issue or not. Since it works in the BIOS, we can return to the drives for Windows.

In device manager, expand "Universal Serial Bus controllers", right click on the "Host Controller" and Uninstall.

Failing that, the driver can be downloaded here http://drivers.softpedia.com/dyn-postdownload.php?p=43160&t=0&i=1 . When downloaded, open Device manager, find the USB keyboard (with the yellow exclamation mark), right click, properties. Open 2nd tab called Driver, and click Update driver. Then, click on Browse my computer for driver software.

[image]

Click browse and select the new .dll file.

Comment: I downloaded the driver that you say me.

Later, in the Device Manage, double click in "USB Keyboard" -> "Driver Update" -> "Search Software Controller in this computer" and I select the folder that I downloaded previously.

And now, the window show: "Windows can't install the USB Keyboard" - "Windows can't find the controller software for this device" :S

Comment: @user1522176 - No, you need to select Browse my computer (see my updated post)

Comment: Yes, is the same that I did. It just that in my computer, is in spanish, and the button is: "Search my computer for driver software" - "Search and install driver software manually".

I did this, and when I selected the folder which contain the .dll file, Windows says me that it can't install the USB Keyboard :(

I don't know why

Comment: In that case, I'm sorry, I would email Genius and see if they reply.

Comment: Oh :(, I understand it.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Have you checked in the BIOS to make sure that it has the "Legacy USB Device" support turned on?

Comment: I have checked the options in my BIOS, and It doesn't have any option called "Legacy USB Device".

Actually, my BIOS has very little options, only the boot sequence and little bit more.

Comment: @Stark: The KB220V10.zip that Dave Rook linked to on SoftPedia seems to contain a setup program - did you try that? (Also, Dave, when installing drivers don't you point to a .INF, not .DLL?)

Comment: @Karan: Yes, I also installed from setup.exe, but that didn't work.

Maybe, it(KB220V10.zip) may not be the correct file? This file is for KB 220, and my keyboard is KB-M220.

I don't know.

Comment: @karan - Yes, sorry, I did mean .inf file.

Comment: Sorry but I was of holidays and I wasn't at home.

Anyone else who can help me? my keyboard is still not working :(

Thanks